# Saving the coordinates of multiple points in OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, geojson

I'm using OpenLayers3 and would like to have map where a user can draw 1 or more points.
I already implemented that. However, I'd also like to save the coordinates of every point.

But I don't really know how to do that, since OpenLayers3 is rather new and I'm having a hard time finding examples online.

This is what I have so far:

```
var modeSelect = document.getElementById('type');
var draw; // global so we can remove it later

//modify 
var featureOverlay = new ol.FeatureOverlay({
  style: new ol.style.Style({
    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
      color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
    }),
    stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
      color: '#ffcc33',
      width: 2
    }),
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 7,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
      })
    })
  })
});
featureOverlay.setMap(map);
// modify end

function addInteraction() {
    var value = modeSelect.value;
    if (value == 'Point') {
        draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
          //source: source,
          features: featureOverlay.getFeatures(),
          type: /** @type {ol.geom.GeometryType} */ (value)
        });
        map.addInteraction(draw);
    }
    // modify
    if (value == 'Modify') {
        var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
            features: featureOverlay.getFeatures(),
            // the SHIFT key must be pressed to delete vertices, so
            // that new vertices can be drawn at the same position
            // of existing vertices
            deleteCondition: function(event) {
            return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(event) &&
                ol.events.condition.singleClick(event);
          }
        });
        map.addInteraction(modify);
    } 
}
addInteraction();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I came up with a solution that is at least a step in the right direction.
I rearranged the code in general and implemented this function:

```
function saveData() {
    // save it as geojson
    var format = new ol.format['GeoJSON']();
    // this will be the data in the chosen format
    var data;

    try {
    // convert the data of the vector_layer into the chosen format
    data = format.writeFeatures(vector_layer.getSource().getFeatures());
    } catch (e) {
    // at time of creation there is an error in the GPX format (18.7.2014)
    $('#data').val(e.name + ": " + e.message);
    return;
    }

    $('#data').val(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));

}
```

I'm still struggling to write it to an actual .json-file on the server though,
but I'm pretty confident I'll find a solution.

EDIT:

It was pretty simple actually. Just wrote this piece of php that does all the work:

```
    <?php

    include 'dbconnection.php';


        $str="INSERT INTO multipoint_tabelle (id, geom) VALUES (1,(SELECT ST_Multi(ST_Union(geom)) FROM punkttabelle));";
        $test_str=pg_query($conn, $str);


    // write GeoJSON 

        $json = $_POST['json'];
        //$points_coords = $_POST['coords'];

        if (json_decode($json) != null) { /* sanity check */

        // w+ Read/Write. Opens and clears the contents of file; or creates a new file if it doesn't exist
            $file = fopen('points.json','w+');
            fwrite($file, $json);
            fclose($file);
        } else {

        // handle error 
        }


?>
```

Comment: -1 for just showing snippets, would like to see a complete jsFiddle code, or something like that. For example in your javascript code: what is vector_layer? What triggers the save function, a button, or a map feature event?

Comment: Searched your code snippet and found this complete working code:

http://codepen.io/barbalex/pen/fBpyb